# How to set legend of different plots depending on the category?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, legend

I have a large dataset, with more than 7000 rows and 300 columns. I am dealing with diagnoses and length of stay. I want to do a plot for every diagnose (So in  the `xlabel` will be as much bars as patients, and in `ylabel` is the number of days for each patient that had that diagnose).

However, I want to have a different title for every plot, in order to know to each diagnose that plot refers to. I mean, for heart attack, for example, I want the title to be "heart attack" but then, for a different diagnose, I want another title. I want it to do in a automatically way. Is that possible? I show my code below, but I know it is not correct.

Furthermore, I want the `xlabel` and `ylabel` appear in every plot, what It is not happening right know. It just appears in the last one.

Can anyone help me?

```
df_n = df[['Diagnose','Length of Stay']]
df_n.groupby('Diagnose').plot(kind = 'bar')
plt.xlabel('Patients')
plt.ylabel('Length of Stay (Days)')
plt.title('Length of Stay for Diagnose') # I want it to be the name of the diagnose
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your labels are not showing because you have not explicitly set them for each plot that you will make. 
When I do `groupby` I like making dictionaries. Each diagnoses will be a key, and the value will be the dataframe

```
a = dict(tuple(df_n.groupby('Diagnose')))
for key, value in a.items():
     value.plot(kind = 'bar')
     plt.title('{}'.format(key))
```

Under the for loop, you can set all your formats once, and it will do this for everygraph. You can put in a `plt.savefig('{0}.eps'.format(k)` statement and this will save all your plots